# Echo confirm javascript with php

Tags: javascript, php, confirm, delete-row

I was wondering. Is there some possible way to echo a confirm javascript to confirm if delete values from database or not
what i'm trying to do is this:

```
 echo($strconfirm ="<script>javascript:confirm('Tem a certeza que pretende eliminar o registo?');</script>");

                if ($strconfirm == true)
                {

                    $query="DELETE FROM softwares WHERE Idsoft='".$id."'";
                    $result=mysqli_query($ligabd,$query);
                    if (!$result)
                    {
                        echo("<script>javascript:alert('Erro ao eliminar o produto!');window.location='produtos.php';</script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo("<script>javascript:alert('Software eliminado com sucesso!');window.location='produtos.php';</script>");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    header("location:produtos.php");
                }
```

Comment: PHP and JavaScript do not interact...What you are trying to do is impossible with that pattern.

Comment: JS alert has to be triggered by a JS event. You can't just inject alert to website and hope it works. In other words: no, not possible. My advice: confirm with a modal window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it that way:
A user confirms the delete and Javascript launches an ajax request to some PHP page. This page deletes the data and then answers in JSON. Javascript parses JSON and says if the operation was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be done using AJAX and PHP, for example:
You can embed JavaScript inside PHP such as

```
   echo "<script>var confirm = confirm("Are you sure?");
          if(confirm){ 
             //Call PHP with AJAX here 
           }
          </script>";
```

But if you use AJAX you don't need to embed your code inside PHP, you can write all your JavaScript code in a separate file and make PHP requests using AJAX.

If you want a real example, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm actions are meant to go inside javascript statements, they return true or false. Like so:

```
if(confirm("Save file?")){
        // Do somethign if use clicks OK
    } else {
        // Do somethign if use clicks Cancel
    }
```

So, your code should be something like:

```
<?php
 echo("<script>if(confirm('Tem a certeza que pretende eliminar o registo?')){
    // Use AJAX here to send Query to a PHP file
 } else {
    window.location='produtos.php';
 };</script>");
?>
```

Basically, this should be handled with an AJAX query.